# Правильное разделение интерфейсов

Tags: c#, проектирование

Есть legacy проект и массивные классы моделей, где они представлены как есть.  В них много свойств которые можно разделить на множество разных интерфейсов (сегрегация интерфейсов).

```
class FatModel : IFoo, IBar, IZaa...
```

Требуется передать экземпляр этого класса в слой приложения где нужен IFoo и немного IBar

И тут напрашиваются варианты

1. Создать обобщенный интерфейс.

   ```
   interface IFooBar : IFoo, IBar
   class FatModel : IFooBar, IZaa...
   ```

   Но получается ерунда, потому что эти обобщенные интерфейсы плодятся как кролики. Создав обобщенный интерфейс на 2 интерфейса обязательно появится тот, кому нужны 3 или другие 2...и в разных комбинациях.
2. Передать объект как есть и в нужных местах делать каст к нужному интерфейсу.

   Но в этом случае все проверки типов уходят в рантайм, что плохо.
3. Адаптеры, где будут представлены нужные свойства?

   Никогда не делал адаптеров для моделей и полезности такого решения не знаю.

Какие есть еще варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнём с того, что интерфейс (и классы, его реализующие) должен отображать предметную область.

> Требуется передать экземпляр этого класса в слой приложения где нужен IFoo и немного IBar

Если комбинация `IFoo` и `IBar` имеет прикладное значение - её было бы нелишним ввести. Тогда всё очевидно просто, правда, переписывать legacy вряд ли захочется ради этого.

Если комбинация интерфейсов прикладного значения не имеет, то и метод, который требует и того и другого одновременно - тоже не имеет прикладного значения.
Простой вариант решения этой проблемы - выделение двух методов, один из которых требует `IFoo`, второй - `IBar`.

UPD: не подумал сразу, но можно же сделать генерик метод, который указывает требования:

```
    static void Method<T>(T obj) where T : IFoo, IBar
```

Comment: Это теория, а на практике мы имеем 1) IFoo и IBar используются в разных местах слоя и 2 метода просто ввести нереально, только обобщенный интерфейс 2) взрывной рост обобщенных интерфейсов из-за того, что каждый сервис брал те поля, что хотел и не получается четко разделить свойства по интерфейсам, а переписывать логику приложения вообще не вариант, даже с адаптерами меньше возни будет

Comment: @vitidev а много у вас классов, которым реально нужен этот метод? Может проще для каждого из них обертку создать и всё? Я понимаю о чём вы, но нормальные решения таки придуманы для ООП, когда каждый "предметный" метод четко знает, для кого в предметной области он написан.

Comment: У меня много методов которым нужен этот класс. Причем внутри себя они используют из него все, что хотят причем глубоко внутри себя. Когда я создаю свою модель, чтобы использовать ее в тех же методах я вынужден либо сделать IFatModel и в мою модель внести кучу ненужного ей хлама, либо раздербанить FatModel на интерфейсы, но оно не делится.(ну разве что каждому сервису создавай свой интерфейс и сделать обертку, в который впихнуть все эти интерфейсы - работоспособно но костыль жесткий)

Comment: @vitidev добавил UPD, может такой вариант вас устроит?

Comment: Никогда в голову не приходил такой подход. На первый взгляд работоспособно, но нужно проверить. Также непонятно костыль это или нормальная практика.

Comment: @vitidev если решение помогло - отметье "галочкой".